# Jenkins - Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: jenkins, github, executable, pull-request

I'm trying to setup the Jenkins Github Pull-Request Builder on a Jenkins node slave, however when I set the refspec to `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`.

The build fails, saying that I couldn't fetch the repo, When the refspec removed, keeping everything else in place (Github pull request builder ticked and configured, branch specifier is set to ${sha1} defaulted to master using string parameter, the build is fine.

Here is the error trace:

```
git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.blah.company.com:organization/repository.git
+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.blah.company.com:organization/repository.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:763)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1012)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1043)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1277)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.blah.company.com:organization/repository.git +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*" returned status code 1:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. clearing out the **workspace** files of the required job.
2. rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks, this answer has been helpful. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain how it impacts a build?

Comment: @AlexanderTunick, Hi :) 
AFAIK cleans up the artifacts left over from the previous builds,
and ensures that the local environment is healthy

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because I switched from SVN to git. So I had an exisiting jenkins job with svn. In this job I just changed the source `source-code-management` to git. Due to this changing I had an exisiting workspace and by default in this scenario the git client just calls `fetch` and not as required `git clone`.

To fix it you have to set `Additional Behaviours` below `source-code-management` to `Wipe out repository & force clone`.

Also see [jenkins migration from svn to git](https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/jenkins-migration-from-svn-to-git)

Answer (score 0):

Reason I saw that was because jenkins disk was full for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the workspace directory file permissions were insufficient. The jenkins user has to be the owner of the workspace directory. Having the permissions for the jenkins GROUP is not enough!

```
# jenkins is owner
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/www/jenkins/workspace/ 

# add jenkins group
sudo chgrp -R jenkins /var/www/jenkins/workspace/ 

# add other groups that need access
sudo chgrp -R othergroup /var/www/jenkins/workspace/ 

# add full owner permissions + any other group permissions you need
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/jenkins/workspace/
```